# How will I stop Ajax request service from anonymous user in Tikiwiki?

Tags: tiki-wiki

I found an Ajax service running as I called my Event tracker calendar. 
[myserver]/tiki-tracker_calendar-list?trackerId=30&beginField=startDate&endField=endDate&resourceField=title&coloringField=null&filters=%0D%0A%7Bfilter%20field%3D%22tracker_field_eventCategory%22%20content%3D%22%22%7D%0D%0A&start=1488085200&end=1491710400&_=1490626987241

If the attacker leverage this and enter:
tiki-tracker_calendar-list?trackerId=30&beginField=startDate&endField=endDate&start=0&end=9999999999
The system will return all the events in tracker 30. 
I tried to enter:
`if (! isset($user))

{

header('Location: index.php');

die;

}`
in File: /var/www/html/tikisvn15/tiki-ajax_services.php

At line 35

It works. Is there any other way? Would my modification stop the Ajax service from other components?

Answer (score 1):

You can set which groups can see what using the Tiki permissions system. [See the documentation here](https://doc.tiki.org/permissions)

**Note** that once you have set your tracker not to be visible for anonymous (*not logged in*) users you will need to rebuild your search index (on Control Panels -> Search) because TrackerCalendar uses the search index extensively.

I would advise against putting arbitrary user checks like this in the tiki code as things will stop working and it will be very hard to work out why, i think.

Comment: Worked. However, it still show an empty array as I enter the URL. I guess I live with that.

Comment: Yes, the empty array returned is because it may not be an error that no items are visible - tracker permissions are so complex: you can adjust viewing permissions globally, or per tracker, or by category, or status or even "ownership", so returning an error if nothing is visible would not be useful in many cases. 
Glad it worked for you though, welcome to Tiki!